# Collision triggers without direct attachment to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a very amateur question and I'm not entirely sure how to title it. Essentially I want to use the `OnCollisionEnter2D` method for multiple (while separate) game objects in the same script, rather than a script for each separate game object.

I've tried the following with no success:

```cs
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
        {
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Ballone")
            {
                charge += 1;
            }
        }
```

I believe this isn't functioning properly because it's attached to a script for my event system, but I'm not sure how to change the syntax.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I simply do not know how to do it. I'm aware of how to use ```OnCollisionEnter2D```. Is it universal? Can I use an "if" statement to solve my problem for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnCollisionEnter2D is an event handler.

During FixedUpdate when Unity performs collision calculations, it notifies colliders about whether they have collided and passes them the relevant Collision2D object.  If that collider is attached to an object with a script component that has a OnCollisionEnter2D method, then the Collision2D object is passed into that method and the collision is handled.

In that context, it doesn't make sense for an unrelated object to handle OnCollisionEnter2D events that belong to other objects.  However, you can capture the events on each object and then pass those events (or data from those events) to another more "general purpose" method in another script if you want.

E.g

Create a class and method to handle your collisions then attach it to a GameObject in the scene such as an empty GameObject named CollisionManager

```
class CollisionManagerScr : MonoBehaviour {

    public void HandleCollision(GameObject collidingObject, Collision2D col) {
        Debug.Log("I've managed this collision with " + collidingObject.name);
        Debug.Log(col) // Some info about the Collision2D object
    }
}
```

Then, attach a script to the objects that you want to check for collision on:

```
public class MyCollisionScript : MonoBehaviour {
    
    private CollisionManagerScr colManager;

    void Start() {
        colManager = GameObject.Find("CollisionManager").GetComponent<CollisionManagerScr>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.name.equals("Ballone")) {
             if (colManager != null) {
                 colManager.HandleCollision(this, col); // Passes in the object that detected the collision
                 colManager.HandleCollision(col.gameObject, col) // Passes in the Ballone object
             }
        }
    }

}
```

Now, whenever OnCollisionEnter2D is triggered for those objects, it calls HandleCollision.  HandleCollision can then do whatever you want it to do.  There undoubtedly is a use case for something like this but it ***smells a lot like unnecessary abstraction to me.***

*Please bear in mind that I wrote this on the fly so there could be problems/typos etc.  Also, this is just one potential approach.  You could also implement an approach that is effectively the same using EventHandlers etc. but that is just adding an additional event handling layer to the existing event handling layer.*

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thank you so much. I kept looking for documentation on this and I just couldn't find it.